# Ler objetos através da classe Scanner

Tags: java, array, orientação-a-objetos, herança, scanner

[![FOTO DO CÓDIGO][1]][1]

Não estou conseguindo instanciar um objeto e lê-lo com o método da classe Scanner. É possível fazer algo do tipo?

```
Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);


Notas notas [] = new Notas [3];

for (int i =0; i< notas){

System.out.println("Digite a nota");
notas[i] = s.nextNotas();

}
```

Nesse caso, "Notas" seria uma outra classe.

Answer (score -2):

Acredito que a melhor forma seria:

```
for (int i =0; i< notas.size();i++){

System.out.println("Digite a nota " + i);
notas[i] = s.nextInt();

}
```